# E: unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the same error. I tried the 4 steps (http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) and when I do :

sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full

I get the error.

```
E: unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full
```

When I check for the **ros-latest.list**, I get the following output:

```
....@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list 

deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu vivid main
```

Let me know what might be going on.

I am running ubuntu 15.04 on vmware player

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208184/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-desktop-full/) by [tosandip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22300/tosandip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-29**:
you have done sudo apt-get update ?

**Comment by [tosandip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22300/tosandip/) on 2015-04-29**:
Yes that passes without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in [step 1.2](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu#indigo.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list) of the page you linked

> Setup your computer to accept software from packages.ros.org. ROS Indigo ONLY supports Saucy (13.10) and Trusty (14.04) for debian packages.

That means if you are using 15.04, you will need to build ROS from source.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tosandip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22300/tosandip/) on 2015-04-29**:
Thanks for pointing this out. I am now trying to build ROS from source using the following link: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source

This is failing at step [2.1.2](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source#Building_the_catkin_Packages)

"could not have their rosdep keys resolved"

**Comment by [tosandip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22300/tosandip/) on 2015-04-29**:
I think I am going to give up and install 14.04.2 which is supported.